# space between words in JS

Tags: javascript, html, popup, space

I have this JS code:

```
function myPopUp()
{
    var y;
    var name=prompt("Please enter your name"," הכנס את שמך");
    if (name!=null)
    {
        y= '  How are you today?';
        document.getElementById("popup").innerHTML = y;
        var x="";
        var time=new Date().getHours();
        if (time<20)
        {
            x="Have a nice day" +  name + '!';
        }
        else
        {
            x='   Great evening  '+ name +'   !  ';
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerText = x ;
    }
}
```

with this HTML code:

```
<body>
    <button onclick="myPopUp()" >לחץ כאן</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <p id="popup"></p>
</body>
```

My question: When someone write their name there is no space between the words?  How do I put a space between words in JS?

Thank you.

Comment: WHERE are you missing the spaces?

Comment: if (time<20)
  {
  x="Have a nice day" +  name + '!';
  }
else
  {
  x='   Great evening  '+ name +'   !  ';
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need a space after "day," so try this:

```
x="Have a nice day " +  name + '!';
```

Comment: You're welcome.  Please remember to mark answer as correct :)

Answer (score 2):

In HTML, extra white space is collapsed to a single space (ASCII 32) character.

If you MUST force a space, use the html identity `&nbsp;` which is a non-breaking space.

Better yet, use CSS to put margins around your element and make the spacing visual.

Comment: the problem is in the JS, not in the HTML file

Comment: The JS in this case updates HTML, so the two are extremely interconnected.  You didn't say *which* line was giving you trouble though, so I had assumed it was the widely spaced out one.

Comment: the problem is here 

if (time<20)
  {
  x="Have a nice day" +  name + '!';
  }
else
  {
  x='   Great evening  '+ name +'   !  ';
  }